# How do I add values to a textbox from a listbox using C#?

Tags: c#

I a subtotal for each item in a list Box, but I want to create a running subtotal in a text Box when I press a button, "Add to Order"

I'm not sure what kind of coding I would need, if it is an "if" statement or for statement

Comment: You want to add listbox item values and display it to a textbox?

Comment: I have two items, pizza that costs $9.50 and sandwiches that cost $5.00. They can order as many items of each item as they want. When they click add to order, the type food and and quantity and line item price goes into the listbox, but I also want a running subtotal in a textbox of all the orders combined.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the values in the listbox.

```
string value = "The items you selected are:\r\n\r\n";
foreach (var item in ListBox1.Items)
{
   value += "," + item.ToString(); 
}

TextBox1.Text = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in ListBox1.Items)
{
   value += "," + item.ToString(); 
}

txtTotal.Text = value;
```